# simplexml_load_file not working with codeigniter Php

Tags: php, xml, codeigniter

I want to get response from url, I used XML helper but cant fetch records, how can i do this?

I tried with following code, where am I going wrong?

```
$checkurl = "http://im-api1.webpurify.com/services/rest/?method=webpurify.aim.imgcheck&api_key=xxxxxxx&imgurl=http://mydomain/img/preiview4.jpg";
$response = simplexml_load_file($checkurl,'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA);
echo "<pre>";print_R($response);
```

And in url i am getting following result

```
<rsp stat="ok">
<method>webpurify.aim.imgcheck</method>
<format>rest</format>
<nudity>98</nudity>
<api_key>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</api_key>
</rsp>
```

Comment: What should the expected response be?

Comment: I want response in Array or json , i just want result from url (xml)

Comment: What is the exact problem? Does the API return invalid data?

Comment: @NicoHaase: api not working

Comment: Then you should better ask the provider of your API about how to use it